# Excel add-in: Excel.CustomFunctionDimensionality.matrix is not a recognized type

Tags: excel, typescript, office-js, custom-functions-excel

So, I'm trying to create a custom function that takes a range as a parameter, and I'm following the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-parameter-options?tabs=javascript#range-parameters - According to this, passing in a range SHOULD pass the data in as a 2D matrix, which would be ideal.

However, I'm using TypeScript, and it doesn't seem like `Excel.CustomFunctionDimensionality.matrix` (which is what the guide said the type is) is a valid type. In fact, it can't even find "CustomFunctionDimensionality" (and I can't find references to it anywhere else in the documentation). I've tried using `any[][]`, but that doesn't seem to work. Either way, I get #CALC! errors when trying to pass in a range, due to an "unliftable array" I assume this is because it doesn't know that a range is a valid data type for my function, but I'm not sure.

As a workaround, I let this param be a string, and pass the range address in as a string, and manually grab the data in my function, but this is clunky and counter-intuitive, so I'd really like to get this fixed.

for context, my function declaration looks like this:

`export function distinct(range: string | any[][]): Promise<number>`

Comment: If you use [Scriptlab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) and copy the sample to code editor and register the function, you will find the sample works. You may notice that the sample code is JavaScript instead of TypeScript. You may can share your project here which is much helpful for debugging.

Comment: Yes, my issue isn't with the sample. The issue is that my add-in, which is written in TS, doesn't seem to like ranges being passed to it. I've updated my question to point out that the #CALC! errors are due to "unliftable array"s, so it seems like Excel doesn't realize my function can handle ranges. The problem occurs before anything enters the body of my function, so it's happening somewhere within the black box of Excel itself. I assume I have to do something to let Excel know this function can handle ranges, but I'm not sure how to do that in a TypeScrpt based project.